# Ошибки на сайте (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: php

Возникла проблема с сайтом. Выдает такие ошибки:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ll in /var/www/administrator/.md5 on line 169

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/templates/beez_20/index.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: in /var/www/administrator/.md5 on line 139
```

Как это можно исправить?

первые строки /var/templates/beez_20/index.php

```
  <?php
/**
 * @package                Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  Templates.beez_20
 * @copyright        Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license                GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
     // check modules
$showRightColumn  = ($this->countModules('position-3') or $this->countModules('position-6') or $this->countModules('position-8'));
$showbottom      = ($this->countModules('position-9') or $this->countModules('position-10') or $this->countModules('position-11'));
$showleft      = ($this->countModules('position-4') or $this->countModules('position-7') or $this->countModules('position-5'));

if ($showRightColumn==0 and $showleft==0) {
  $showno = 0;
```

Comment: А содержимое файлов в районе указанных строк где? Здесь не шоу "Битва экстрасенсов".

Comment: А покажите файл template.php или как-то так в /var/templates/beez_20/

Comment: @tCode есть только templateDetails.xml

Comment: Вспомнил, там есть папка Layout

Comment: @tCode нет такой(

Comment: скорее всего у вас лишний пробел перед `<?php`  + проверьте кодировку файла `index.php` - установите UTF без BOM